# I am unable make file or directory in Visual Studio Code in Win Subsystem for Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_add-a-source-code-file). When I take the step "Add a source code file", I am shown this report:

```
Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-20.04/home/alex/TEST/helloworld/helloworld' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/alex/TEST/helloworld/helloworld')
```

I don't know what to do, can some one help me?

Comment: I think that may be you problem come for use `sudo` to create the directory, this is not necesary in your own home folder. Take care on this.

Comment: happens for me when creating a file using `docker-compose exec..` strange but heyho

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The VScode needs permissions thus

Try this command on your WSL terminal

```
sudo chown -R username /path/to/working/directory
```

Replace :

'username' with your username and the path of your directory

Comment: if you experience the same issue with saving open file in VS code, try the following too:

`sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file`. This will fix permission for the file (allowing everything, not just reading)

Comment: Doesn't work. Even running npm install as `sudo` results in the same `EACCES: permission denied, rename` error

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same problem and changing ownership via `sudo chown -R username <path>` did not work for me.

Simple solution!
My issue: Downloaded files for coursera project in zip. Copied files to ubuntu home/taylor/projects folder. and then tried accessing in vscode with code . I received the read error.

Solution:

1. go to your linux terminal.
2. Access the folder containing the files you are trying to work on.
   For Example: app.py forms.py models.py in the projects folder. got to projects folder.
3. ~/projects ls
   app.py forms.py moodels.py routes.py
   #they should be white meaning know permissions granted.

4. grant permissions

a. `sudo chmod 777 app.py forms.py models.py routes.py`
or
b. `sudo chmod +rwx app.py forms.py models.py routes.py #r=read w=write x=execute`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following steps for windows subsystem for linux (wsl):

1. Open WSL.
2. Navigate to the directory where you want to modify read/write/execute permissions in WSL. Use command:

```
cd nameofdirectory/
```

3. Then type

```
pwd
```

It will show the path of your directory.

4. Then type

```
sudo chown -R username pathofdirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the above one by @uday Pratap, If not Working try this one's :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 folder_name_where_your_file_exists 

or

sudo chmod -R 755 folder_name_where_your_file_exists
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the above fixed it but in my case, i thought it would be more of work having to type this for different files and even with -R , it didnt, you still have to chown each reach file. i simply changed the umask of my user eg /home/username to 0000 with the command umask 0000. this will permanently allow you to edit any new file as well. its best to ensure your user home is secure so no one else have access to your home files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35470631)