# "Make install" fails in WSL2 (permission denied)

Tags: makefile, wsl-2

I have set up my development environment in WSL2 on Windows 10 20H2.

I have set up everything in the same way as on Linux Mint, that I am also using and there are no issues.

On WSL2 I can get "make" command to work (sometimes it fails and shows some permission denied errors, but very often after restart succeeds). But I am not able to get the "make install" command working. It is always failing. The very first time I entered "make install" I got an error about failure to access tomcat directory (permission denied).

Also, very often I get permission denied with "git clean -fdx", but sometimes it succeeds :)

Now I am getting the following errors:

```
$ make install
installing git hooks
cp: cannot create regular file '.git/hooks/DPAuthors.pm': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '.git/hooks/DPChecked.pm': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '.git/hooks/DPCommitHooks.pm': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '.git/hooks/DPUsers.pm': Permission denied
make: *** [src/bios/script/Makefile:698: githooksinstall] Error 1
```

Any hints what could be the issue?

EDIT: it worked now when logged in as root. So how can I fix the permissions to be able to use make without root?

Comment: Could be anything, need info. What project is this? `make install` could do anything or nothing depending what's in the makefile. And where do you put your project? In a folder shared with windows (and other services) or private to WSL? Any chance `make` or `git` uses windows install of git and make (cygwin)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe related to this?

> [I am unable make file or directory in Visual Studio Code in Win Subsystem for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142801/i-am-unable-make-file-or-directory-in-visual-studio-code-in-win-subsystem-for-li)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281748/12669100) from **Uday Pratap Singh**

> The VScode needs permissions thus.
>
> Try this command on your WSL terminal
>
> `sudo chown -R username /path/to/working/directory`
>
> Replace :
>
> 'username' with your username and the path of your directory