# VS Code: NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to save a file called app.js on a folder called js.

Vs Code pop up this:

> Failed to save 'app.js': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://wsl+ubuntu-18.04/js/app.js'
> (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/js')

I tried:

`sudo chown -R user /mnt/c/Users/myUser/Documents/myFolder/proyectFolder`

but I still can't save this file.

Comment: It was as simple as giving permissions to the folder for me as described in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281748/532489

Answer (score 172):

**Try this, fixed it for me**

```bash
sudo chown -R username path
```

**Example:**

```bash
sudo chown -R emanuel /home/emanuel/test/
```

Comment: this should be mark as answer. perfectly work for me

Comment: be careful when connected over ssh. I had to restart my AWS EC2 instance because root login was not permitted

Comment: On a vscode devcontainer your username is `vscode` nor "your" real username

Comment: use "whoami" to check which user you are logged in to

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04. I was using vscode.

Answer (score 14):

In the SSH terminal:

Recommended:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 777 folder_name_where_your_file_exists
```

or

```bash
sudo chmod -R 755 folder_name_where_your_file_exists
```

Answer (score 3):

TLDR;

If you're using a docker container, avoid making files from within the container because the owner and group permissions may cause problems with your editor (in my case VS Code)

---

I was running docker container for a Django project from Windows Terminal and using VS Code to edit my code.

It is a Linux file (since everything in Linux is a file) permission problem that arises because the files don't have proper user and/or group permissions. So VS Code tries to tell us that.

The problem I found only happened when I created files from within my docker container.

- I would run `docker exec ... bash`
- make new files using `touch /path/to/file` from the container bash
- then try to edit those files on VS Code (say urls.py) only to get the scary permissions error preventing the file from saving.

I suspect that making files from within the container embellishes those files with different owner and group settings than your system would default to if you just ran the commands locally (not in the container).

Changing the file permissions with `chown -hR` and `chgrp -hR` would do the trick but to avoid the error altogether I stopped making files from within the container.

Answer (score 2):

Install the extension [Save as Root in Remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.save-as-root) in VS code.

- While saving press Ctrl + Shift + P.
- This open the command palette.
- Search *Save as Root*

Answer (score 1):

Try activating polling:

This worked for me during I tried using wsl.

[image]

Comment: I'm running into this same issue and nothing happened when I selected polling.

Comment: I tried upgrading to wsl2 and it fixed the issue too

Answer (score 1):

The below is for individual file:

> sudo chown yourUserNAme filename

For an entire directory it will be (when you write ls to terminal, you should see your directory to execute this command):

> sudo chown yourUserNAme dirName

For recursive (i.e files and folders inside a folder):

> sudo chown -R yourUserNAme dirName

Note: yourUserNAme is, if you do pwd under any Documents, you will see the path: /home/jhon/Documents. Here user is jhon.

Answer (score 1):

Run VS Code as administrator and it will fix the problem.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-in-vs-code-destination-directory-and-says/e70dc626-6b12-4791-a960-8b704e57098d

Answer (score 0):

It is a Linux user permissions problem.
you should use the command:

```bash
    sudo chown -R $USER:$USER.
```