# Unable to create / edit files as non-root through Samba mount

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, permissions, chmod, samba

I'm trying to setup a code-server (vscode in browser) instance and read/write from a mounted samba share. Unfortunately when I try to add a file it gives me an error that I do not have permissions to read/write to that folder. When I try to add files with the same credentials on Windows it does work though. This is the error that VSCode gives me:

> Unable to write file
> 'vscode-remote://localhost:8080/home/user/repository/test'
> (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied,
> open '/home/gmetitieri/user/test')

If I `sudo touch file.txt` then the file will be created and added. I already used chmod and added full access to the folder but it still won't work. Is this a credentials thing or am I missing something?

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66496890/vs-code-nopermissions-filesystemerror-error-eacces-permission-denied) answer but it still doesn't let me write as non-root

Edit: This is the command I used to mount the drive (just with different folder names and IP address):

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.examplecredentials //192.168.18.112/sharedDir /media/share
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering "non-root through Samba", especially in new releases of OpenSuse (...15.3 -- 15.4), I do few movements into normal configuration panels (no sudo commands or anything technical).

Using Yast Firewall section -- For now (immediate solution):
I turn off the firewall, then see what you can turn on (after this) to keep the samba working with Microsoft Windows.

More details on how to do this with [images on my website](https://artursamenezes.com/kingdom/software/#samba).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the directory on the Samba share does not have permission for non-root users.

In your `smb4.conf` file:

```
[test]
        comment = Test share
        path = /path/to/directory
        force user = unixuser
        valid users = sambauser
```

In this example, **unixuser** should be the owner of the files in `/path/to/directory`. The user logged into Samba in this example is a user called sambauser.